# Form Input Checkbox Values not showing all the checked boxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, forms

I'm trying to serialize a form to display in JSON format. Most of the fields display in the output, except the checked checkboxes. For some reason, no matter which item item I check in the 'Choose your favorite fruit' section, the result is always 'grapefruit'. Here is an example of the output:

```
    {"name":"Micky 
    Mouse","check":"yes","select":"junkfood","fruit":"Grapefruit","message":"Hi"}
```

What I cannot figure out is why aren't the other boxes that I've checked not showing  in the JSON output. Thanks in advance for helping me.

```js
function validate() {
  var checkBoxVal = [];
  var showChecked = document.myForm.fruit;
  var chkboxLength = showChecked.length;
  var values;
  for (var i = 0; i < chkboxLength; i++) {
    if (showChecked[i].checked) {
      checkBoxVal.push(showChecked[i].value);
    }
  }
  if (checkBoxVal.length == 0)
    return false;

  values = checkBoxVal.join(', ');

  // alert( "You selected: " + values + ".");
  return (storeValues(values));
}


(function() {
  function toJSONString(form) {
    var obj = {};
    var elements = form.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
      var element = elements[i];
      var name = element.name;
      var value = element.value;

      if (name) {
        obj[name] = value;
      }
    }

    return JSON.stringify(obj);
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var form = document.getElementById("test");
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var json = toJSONString(this);
      output.innerHTML = json;

    }, false);

  });

})();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>This will show the output of all the fields in key-value pairs. The results will show on the same page.</p>
  <form id="foodie" action="#" method="post">
    <div>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="yes" />
      <label for="check">Check if you like Fruit</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="select">Select your favorite Food Type</label>
      <select name="select" class="form-control">
        <option value="none" selected="selected">None</option>
        <option value="fruits-veggies">Fruits and Veggies</option>
        <option value="meat-seafood">Meat and Seafood</option>
        <option value="junkfood">Junk Food</option>
      </select>

    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="favFruit"></label>
      <div id="favFruit" onblur="return(validate());">
        <h4>Choose Your Favorite Fruit</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Cherries">Cherries
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Apples">Apples
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Berries">Berries
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Grapes">Grapes
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Pears">Pears
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Grapefruit">Grapefruit
      </div>

    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn" />
    </p>
  </form>
  <pre id="output"></pre>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your checkboxes all have the same name so each will be overwritten with the value of the next - which is why you are getting grapefruit as the value. Either give each a unique name or create an array for them. If you are expecting only one ‘favourite’ fruit then leave the name the same and make the input a radio button group.